# cant take pointer of an element in a std vector

Tags: c++, vector, std, stdvector

I have a problem with std::vector

```
class myType
{
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    myType a1;
    myType a2;
    std::vector<myType> V;
    V.push_back(a1);
    myType* a1ptr = &V.back();
    V.push_back(a2);
}
```

it all works fine before I add a2, the ptr is point to some meaningful memory.
but as soon as i added a2, the ptr is still point to the same place but with some garbage memory.

how is this happened?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a2 into your vector, the vector must resize. This means new memory is allocated and the old vector copied into this new (larger) memory. The old memory is then deallocated. Your pointer is left dangling into this (old) deallocated memory.

If you construct your vector with a size, i.e. std::vector V(2), the vector won;t have to resize and your pointer will keep pointing to the value of a1.

Comment: it seems that std::vector V(2) is not just allocate the memory, it is also trying to fill it will two instances contrcuted with default constructors, since I dont have a default constrcutor in my case, it fails.

Comment: And, even I have a default constructor. It will be 2 elements already in my vector, after I call push_back, the vector size becomes 3

Comment: If you don't have a default constructor then you can define the std::vector and then use reserve() to size it. This will also stop the resize and allow you to use push_back() as you have in your code. If the vector is sized on construction then you would use plain indexing into the vector rather than push_back.